# Could I have a camera complete an animation then follow a path?

Tags: animation, camera, scene, path

Currently I have a camera following a car moving across the scene. The car's animation is repetitive and the camera only follows the car for one repetition. Once it's done with the first repetition i would like the camera to pan away from the car and circle around my scene at a constant speed. Is there a away to animate the camera so once it is done following the car it falls on to a path that circles the scene?

Answer (score 1):

With your camera selected, go to Properties -> Constraints. Add 2 'Child-Of' constraints to the camera. In the first Child-Of constraint, make the target your car. In the second Child-Of constraint, make the target a static object in the scene, such as the ground model.

Go to the **last** frame in which the camera needs to follow the car. Set the first Child-Of influence to 1.0 and keyframe it (hit <kbd>I</kbd> over the influence bar). Then set the second Child-Of influence to 0.0 and keyframe it.

Go to the **very next** frame. Set the first Child-Of influence to 0.0 and keyframe it. Set the second Child-Of influence to 1.0 and keyframe it.
Now you are free to animate the camera with respect to the moving car. Then, you can animate the camera with respect to the scene in general.